# Which one has higher priority in CIP rules -- O or OH?

Tags: organic-chemistry, stereochemistry, electronic-configuration, chirality

I know that if the atom is the same, I have to look at the next atom. In the first choice, Oxygen is not connected to any other atom (besides the chiral carbon). It is an anion. Whereas in the second choice, OH has Hydrogen attached to Oxygen. So how do I decide which one gets higher priority?

Comment: *"oxygen is not connected to any other atom"* — How is that possible? Oxygen needs two bonds. Unless you're talking about an anion, or a radical, perhaps? Could you clarify?

Comment: Sorry, Oxygen is an anion, so it is bonded to only the chiral carbon.

Comment: A lone pair on an anion is considered to be a substituent that has an atomic number of 0

Comment: @SafdarFaisal I see, so in this case, OH will get the higher priority, as H has an atomic number of 1?